# How to stop the terminal from running when an async function is complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

When my code completes its processes, the terminal just keeps running and I need to manually close it down. In the past, I used mongoose.disconnect() and that seemed to shut it down, but that hasn't worked here because when I use that (even with an await), it shuts down before all of the 8,000+ records are written to my database.

Here's a sample of the code:

```
const MyFunction = array => {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const item = new Item({
      property1: array[i].property1,
      property2: array[i].property2,
    });
    item.save();
  }
};

const Final = async () => {
  try {
    const array = [{property1, property2}] // 8,000 items long
    await SharedFunctions.connectToMongoDb();
    await MyFunction(array);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

Final();
```

Comment: `process.exit()` ?

Comment: @nopassport1 Thanks for the suggestion but putting await process.exit() below await MyFunction() exits the process before all 8,000 records are pushed to my database (this process takes about 2 minutes to complete). Is there a promise somewhere that I can catch from my mongodb database that might say "alright we got all 8,000 records you can process.exit() ?"

Comment: Is it possible to use a `.then` for your function and within that, a `process.exit()`? So that it only exits when the function is done whatever it's doing?

Comment: @nopassport1 I added some extra code for context. Maybe I'm confused since I'm still fairly new to coding, but doesn't a ".then" essentially do the same thing as "async/await"? And they complete upon a Promise being resolved? In my mind, I've done this by adding "await" before calling MyFunction() - but I might not be thinking of it right. Where would you recommend putting the .then?

Comment: Your `MyFunction` function doesn't return a Promise (i.e. it isn't async) so awaiting it accomplishes nothing

Comment: @Lennholm Thank you, I understand that now. I'm new to creating promises and haven't found great examples online for using them with "for loops". Where would you recommend sticking the Promise in this example?

Comment: @mpc75 It all depends on what `item.save()` does. Does it return a Promise? Then you can use that. Does it take a callback? Then you have to promisify it. After that you also have to deal with the fact that you're looping and creating multiple promises. Do you want them to run in parallell or in sequence?

Comment: @Lennholm thank you for your time and help, Ashish's solution helped me figure out how to refactor to a .map instead of a "for loop" and where to use the Promise. Ashish's (and your suggested) solution worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding node process not being exiting or terminal not exiting, there could be multiple reasons for that. Like open db connections, open handle etc. Node is capabale enough to see if everything is finished and exit the code. You could manually call `process.exit` after `await MyFunction();` to exit but ideally you shouldn't require this.

so I would also suggest to use https://github.com/mafintosh/why-is-node-running package to find any open handles. You need to add it where you expect your program to termninate. So in your case it will be like this

```
const log = require("why-is-node-running");

onst Final = async () => {
  try {
    await SharedFunctions.connectToMongoDb();
    await MyFunction();
    log();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

Final();
```

EDIT: As per your latest edit of question you need to change your MyFunction to be like this

```
const MyFunction = array => {
  return Promise.all(array.map(row => {
    const item = new Item({
      "property1": row.property1,
      "property2": row.property2
    });
    return item.save();
  }));
};
```

Remember that doing so many operation in parallel might cause issues you could also try this

```
const MyFunction = async array => {

  for (const row of array) {
    const item = new Item({
      "property1": row.property1,
      "property2": row.property2
    });
    await item.save();
  }
};
```

Comment: I think I've isolated the issue to the fact that MyFunction() is continuing to write to the database, but it just continues onto the next function in the sequence. So, for example, if I put process.exit() below await MyFunction() it will exit the process when only 300 or so of the 8,000 objects have been sent to my database. Your suggestion is helpful for troubleshooting but I'm not sure it helps solve my problem.

Comment: that is why it is important to fix the root cause. I am sure the problem is in your myFunc which is not dealing with promises properly. If you put your code, I can quickly have a look.

Comment: @mpc75 I have edited my answer for your myFunction. It should work.

Comment: this worked perfectly! I should note, I also added a mongoose.disconnect() at the end of Final() and it all shuts down when all 8,100 records have been saved in my database.